# Rest API version in URL same for related resources or all APIs

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-mvc, jax-rs, resteasy

I am designing REST APIs for some resources in my system. 
System allows users to upload files.

There are 3 kind of resources:

1. Post/GET a file (data file).
2. Get Config files (meta file of file format (format is system specific - like how CSV file in my system should be , how Json file should be etc).
3. Get configfiles of server resources and permissions.

I am thinking of some url of the form:

1. `host/api/v1/files`.
2. `host/api/v1/config/files`.
3. `host/api/v1/config/server`.

Does `host/api/v1/config/files`, `host/api/v1/config/server`
 makes more sense or `host/api/v1/files/config`, `host/api/v1/server/config`
 makes more sense?

Also when version of `config` of `datafiles` changes to `v2` does it make sense to change version of server config files also to `v2` - despite being the fact they are unrelated and don't change together?

Or can I broadly classify files and config of files under same category as
`/host/api/files/v1/data`
`/host/api/files/v1/config`

and server config in another category as
`/host/api/server/v1/config`

Then both can change independently no need to migrate `server/v1/config` to `v2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does host/api/v1/config/files, host/api/v1/config/server makes more sense or host/api/v1/files/config, host/api/v1/server/config makes more sense?

The latter. Think about expanding the service in the future, what if e.g. you want to add a method for getting/adding server users. Its URL should be `host/api/v1/server/config`.

Regarding the versioning, service should be observed as a whole. If you update one part to new version, whole service goes to a new version. If some parts are completely independent, consider making two services.

[IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-version/) states the following:

> It can be argued that, when the interface to a service changes in a
>   non-backwards-compatible way, in reality an entirely new service has
>   been created. In such a case, unless implementations of the first
>   interface continue to exist, the preexisting service is, in effect,
>   discontinued. From the client's perspective, a service is no more than
>   an interface and some non-functional qualities (such as trust and QoS
>   attributes) that it may claim to exhibit; thus, if the interface to a
>   service changes in a non-backwards-compatible way, it no longer
>   represents an instance of the original service, but is rather a
>   completely new service.